# Fgets empty spaces in array

Tags: c

If I use `fgets()` to store a line into an array of characters with a size that is greater than the number of characters what happens to the empty indexes between the last character entered and the string terminator?

For example:

If I use the `fgets` function to scan in a word entered by the user without knowing the length of the word then I have to use an arbitrary length of something like 80 to ensure the word will fit.

```
fgets(word, 80, stdin);
```

but say the user enters: "hello"

This word is only 5 characters (7 with '\0' and '\n'), so what happens to the other 73?

Comment: The status of the remaining buffer is undefined.  The C spec makes no mention of their state.

Comment: BTW: Chances are `user enters: "hello"` means `'h'`, `'e'`, `'l'`, `'l'`, `'o'`, `'\n'`, `'\0'` - 7 `char`.  The more interesting question is "why" do you want to know the state of the remaining buffer - let us get to the real question.

Comment: I wanted to know the state of the remaining buffer because I needed to implement `strcmp()`and I wasn't sure if the remaining buffer had any impact on the return value of the `strncmp()` function.

Comment: If `fgets()` does not return `NULL`, then the buffer is properly `'\0'` terminated and `strncmp()` works with the initial defined portion of the buffer.  The remaining buffer, regardless of its value, make no difference.  If the `fgets()` value returned is `NULL`, there is no need to check the buffer.  The buffer will be unchanged if `NULL` was returned due to `EOF` or undefined if `NULL` return ed due to input error.  IAC, the remaining contents (after `'\0'`) are irrelevant when non-`NULL` returned and the return value from `fgets()` is key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first 7 characters get filled with `'h' , 'e' , 'l' , 'l' , 'o' , '\n' , '\0'`
The rest are left as they were.

Comment: so if the array is initially empty then everything after the 7 characters will just be nothing?

Comment: The array is never empty.  It always contains something, you just might not know what those cells contain if you didn't specifically put something there.